# How to use window() function in a For Loop? (in R)

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a rolling window of a time series. The total sample is 756 observations long and I want to create 496 windows of the length of 260 observations:

First window: 1-260

Second window: 2-261

Last window: 496-755

Comment: I tried  data[ i:260+i-1 ,] but it gave me errors

Comment: `data[ i:260+i-1 , ] ` was close. You probably need `data[ i:(260+i-1) , ] `

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is that R recognizes "i" as a non-numeric argument in math function.

Comment: I have also tried the window(data, start=i, end=260+i-1) command. However, this gives me strange results

Answer (score 0):

I would use rollapply, assuming you want to introduce a certain function you want to apply over a rolling window (for example the mean).

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(c(1:1000),200,mean)
```

Take care, obviously if you want the same length as your original data you have to add Nas in the beginning, the 200 is the width, so in your case 260.

Comment: If you want to add NAs at the beginning use `library(zoo); rollappyr(1:1000, 260, mean, fill = NA)` or if you want partial means at the beginning `rollapplyr(1:1000, 260, mean, partial = TRUE)`